# Как собрать HelloJNI в стандарте C99?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Если добавить в пример HelloJNI из NDK строчку:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) { }
```

пример перестает собираться с ошибкой

*error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode*
*note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code*

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сообщение об ошибке говорит о том, что инициализация внутри цикла допустима только в режиме C99. Нужно включить это режим, добавив опцию компилятора в файл Android.mk.

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c99
```